# Dynamically creating database and data source in ColdFusion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I'm trying to create a database and data source dynamically from the user input.

I'm not sure is that possible or not to create a database using cfquery tag without using data source.

***For Data source creation***

```
<cfscript>
    adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator");
    adminObj.login("admin password");  
    myObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.datasource");
    myObj.setMSSQL(driver="MSSQLServer",
        name="datasourceName", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "1433",
        database = "database", username = "userName", password="password", login_timeout = "30",
        timeout = "20", interval = 7, buffer = "64000", blob_buffer = "64000", setStringParameterAsUnicode = "false",
        description = "", pooling = true, maxpooledstatements = 1000, enableMaxConnections = "true",
        maxConnections = "300", enable_clob = true, enable_blob = true, disable = false, storedProc = true,
        alter = false, grant = true, select = true, update = true, create = true, delete = true, drop = false,
        revoke = false
        );
</cfscript>
```

I've tried to create a data source using above code statically it creating Datasource successfully

***For database creation***

```
<cfquery name="createDB" result="res">
    create database #form.dbname#
</cfquery>
```

but not able to create a database using the above code. I got the error, my objective needs to create database then data source by using the user input string.
[image]

***Any advice or help is appreciable***
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why? I _think_ that it is possible in a round-a-bout way, but ColdFusion server really shouldn't have that level of permissions to your database server. Are you using the `sa` account as your CF user connection, or do you have a specific connection for the CF server?

Comment: It is a _really_ bad idea to let users create databases on your server.

Comment: @shawn yes, I'm using sa account as a cf user connection

Comment: @miguel-F yes, but this is scenario ☺

Comment: You need to use the datasource name in the <cfquery> that creates the database - though, I am not sure that will work. You may need to create the DB using a datasource that already exists and then create the new datasource. Also, I agree with everyone else...this is a bad idea...a very, very bad idea.

Comment: From what I remember, I think you can create another baseline database (like Master in SQL Server) and backup and restore that database. That gets you an actual datasource db to use. However, I'll reiterate again that I think this is a _very_ bad idea.

Comment: I would also HIGHLY recommend that you create a special user for just CF to use and limit that account to what it's allowed to do. `sa` has _A LOT_ of privileges in your database. And you really don't want a web-accessible user to be able to do something like `DROP TABLE master` to your database.

Comment: I'd also take a look at https://www.petefreitag.com/presentations/cfsummit/2016/cf2016-lockdown.pdf.  Pete really knows his stuff, and this guide (and others for applicable versions) are extremely good.

Comment: I suggest putting the code for creating the database into a stored procedure and granting the CF account permission to execute it.

Comment: @DanBracuk _IF_ it really needs to be done. :-)

Comment: One other note I'll add for future readers: One of the reasons this is a bad idea (despite the security aspects) is that you can open up a hole that allows for an easy denial-of-service, intentional or not. If this gets called multiple times, each of these database has a drive space cost. You can fill up the hard drives in your database server pretty quickly. Running out of drive space can be a tremendous headache. And even worse, if you are billed for the drive space you use, you can receive a fairly expensive surprise.

Comment: You didn't mention why you want to grant this power to the user, so I'll just assume you are building an intranet application to maintain databases with a web frontend. If you need flexibility when it comes to database connections, you should disregard `cfquery`/datasources and instead [use the JDBC driver directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). `createObject("java", ...)` will be your tool.

Comment: @Shawn I've solved this scenario by using the master database. yes, that's bad idea but I think that has a solution.

Comment: @Alex Just like CMS concepts. user/site admin need able to create their own database and table via UI (without knowledge of database and ColdFusion).

Comment: `"...create their own database and table via UI (without knowledge of database and ColdFusion)"` <<< Yes, it _is_  possible, but there are plenty of things that can be done but shouldn't be done. What I'm saying is that you are opening yourself up to a **LOT** of problems if you allow this.

Comment: Okay. I agree with you, will try to avoid this scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you convert your script to a function, and pass the desired database name from the form input as an argument?

runCreateDatabase = createDBforMe(databasename=form.dbname)

Comment: You mean you talking about code re usability concept/purpose right?? thanks for your advice 